# Ошибка Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, dle

При нажатии почти любой кнопки(например смена пароля или добавление gift кода) на странице - http://sahtopmine.xyz/cabinet.html высвечивается такая ошибка `Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function` и из-за неё ничего не происходит. JQuery стоит последней версии. **Не слим!** Не знаю как решить проблему. Вот часть кода:

```
function refresh_data(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cabinet/engine/handlers/handler.php",
    data: "operation=" + id,
    success: function(data) {
      var message = JSON.parse(data);
      if (message.type == "success") {
        $('#' + id).html(message.response);
        notif_success(message.text);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Загружена еще какая-то библиотека, которая переопределяет переменную `$`.

---

Вон же оно после `<header>...</header>`:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                                                 ^^^^^
```

Comment: Это в каком файле?

Comment: И какая библиотека это может быть?

Comment: @Tagas3axap4uK Кхм, кхм. Это библиотека jQuery-slim. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши на странице по Вашей ссылке и выберите "View page source".

Comment: О! Я понял, оказывается она ещё внизу была написана. Хорошо я исправил. Но появилась другая ошибка). Связана с SHA рядом. Мне надо его поменять, наверное, но на какой я не знаю(

Comment: Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8='. The resource has been blocked.

Comment: @Tagas3axap4uK "Хорошо я исправил." - Что Вы "исправили"? "slim" убрали что ли? Вы видите, что у Вас два js файла с jQuery включены в страницу?

Comment: Можете подсказать на какой строке, а то что-то не вижу.

Comment: @Tagas3axap4uK Ахренеть. 18 и 169.

Comment: Вроде все дубликаты убрал. Но снова появилась ошибка другая: jquery.js?v=26:10099 POST http://sahtopmine.xyz/cabinet/engine/handlers/handler.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: @Tagas3axap4uK Мне трудно найти ошибку в PHP коде, которого я не вижу. Задайте другой вопрос. На этот я ответил.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо за помощь, вы мне помогли!